# Can I plant this rose shoot?

Tags: roses, cuttings

A rose I bought at a florist is sending off a shoot, and it seems to be doing quite well. Should I plant the entire rose stem or only this shoot? How can I ensure it will survive?

Sorry for the blurry picture.

[image: rose shoot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wish the picture was clearer, but that side shoot looks a bit thin and weak. Roses root easily from cuttings, but you need a stem that either hasn't flowered, or all the flowers have gone, and it should be a young shoot, feeling firm and turgid and usually a bit thicker than that side shoot, more the thickness of the main stem in the picture.

They also root better if they have some leaf left - I can't see the top of the mainstem in the picture, so don't know how long it is, but I think you're more likely to have success rooting the thicker stem than that thin, weak one, though you could try both. For the larger one, shorten it at the bottom a bit, wound the stem, either by scraping down the sides for the bottom inch, or cut into the stem vertically, dip it in rooting hormone if you have any, if not, don't worry, pot up either in sand (not builders sand, silver sand will be fine) or a seed and cutting potting medium or a mix of the two. Water it well. Then you'd need either a plastic bottle with the bottom cut off to pop over the top to keep the cutting humid, or a plastic bag and an elastic band - if you use the bag, you'll need to insert sticks round the edges of the compost to keep the plastic off the cutting. Now stand in a warmish, bright spot, but not in full sun. If its going to root, it should do so within 2-4 weeks, but it may be that the stem has been cut too long for this to work.

If it does root, be prepared for the possibility that it may not be a vigorous grower - many roses are on grafted rootstock, which makes them more vigorous and stronger, so growing some roses on their own roots means you may get a slow to grow, weakish plant.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a rose from the flower shop and propagated the roses with the cuttings in this way. Has been successful! By the way, I followed the instructions of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjdVqK29rRo

[image: propagation of roses at a florist]

[image: propagation of roses by cutting]

[image: propagation of roses by cutting]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's nice to meet you! Thanks for this answer, especially the detailed pictures which are always helpful here. I hope you stay with us and have fun!